# Dropdown Sub-menus with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my Bootstrap navbar and I would like to get a little help about `submenu` because I don't overcome to make `multi-level submenus`.

I have this schema :

[image]

I would like to get `Création Fiches Individuelles (sans n° unique)` and `Création Fiches Individuelles (avec n° unique)` just beside `Création Fiches Individuelles`.

In other words, I would like to place the last box beside `Création Fiches Individuelles` and just click on this submenu to display the last submenu.
Then I just want to display this last level if I put my mouse on `Création Fiches Individuelles` not all the time.

This is the concerning part in my HTML file :

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
                                            </span>  Actes Etat Civil <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                                            </span> Fiches Individuelles 
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                                            <li><a href="{% url "home" %}">Accueil Fiches Individuelles</a></li>

                                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                                <li><a href="#"> Création Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li><a href="{% url "form" %}">Création Fiches Individuelles (sans n° unique) </a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="{% url "form2" %}">Création Fiches Individuelles (à partir n° unique) </a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>

                                            <li><a href="{% url "searched" %}">Consultation Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                            {% if request.user|has_group:"admin" %}
                                            <li><a href="{% url "edited" %}">Edition Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{% url "deleted" %}">Suppression Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
...
```

Is it possible to get some help in order to do that ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In css, this may work.

```
.dropdown-toggle .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu{
    display:none;
}
.dropdown-toggle .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown > li > a:hover .dropdown-menu{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
}
```

However nesting classes like this is not ideal. 
In your html I would add classed to each level of your menu.
    .level-one
    .level-two
    .level-three

etc

Comment: css will make the job, but I would like to display the last level just if I put my mouse on `Création Fiches Individuelles`. Up to now, this last level is always displayed and I don't want ^^

Comment: I have edited my answer to include showing/hiding on hover.